# Proc SQL not joining properly

Tags: sql, proc-sql

This is my code:

```
proc sql;
create table firstjoin as
select a.*
from want a
left join want3 b
on a.date=b.mindate and a.id=b.id;
quit;
```

Where `want` is a table with many rows and dates per ID and `want3` is a table with just one row and date per ID.

`Want` looks something like:

```
Date       | ID | Company | Click 
-----------+----+---------+--------
01/01/2021 | 01 | Us      | 1
01/01/2021 | 01 | Us      | 1
01/01/2021 | 01 | Other   | 1
02/01/2021 | 01 | Us      | 0 
02/01/2021 | 01 | Other   | 0
02/01/2021 | 02 | Us      | 1 
03/01/2021 | 02 | Us      | 1 
03/01/2021 | 02 | Us      | 0
```

And `want3` looks like:

```
MinDate    | ID 
-----------+----
01/01/2021 | 01 
02/01/2021 | 02
```

What I want to do is match both tables so only the first date rows are shown for each ID. That date is the one in `want3`. The result should look like:

```
Date       | ID | Company | Click 
-----------+----+---------+--------
01/01/2021 | 01 | Us      | 1
01/01/2021 | 01 | Us      | 1
01/01/2021 | 01 | Other   | 1
02/01/2021 | 02 | Us      | 1
```

For some reason, when I run this join, the result looks like `want` i.e. there are still many rows and dates per ID.

Comment: Try `inner join`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tryed innerjoin

```
proc sql;
create table firstjoin as
select a.*
from want a
inner join want3 b
on a.date=b.mindate and a.id=b.id;
quit;
```

Comment: that did the trick! Funny how sometimes you can look for complex ways to fix something and the solution is right there in front of you. Thanks!